# Usar variáveis de uma tela principal em uma segunda tela

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8-1

Eu estou fazendo uma aplicação em windows phone, no qual eu tenho a tela principal ( primeira tela ), e nessa tela é feito um cálculo, onde o resultado vai ser exibido em uma segunda tela.
A minha dúvida é a seguinte; Como eu faço para exibir/usar essas variáveis da tela principal nessa segunda tela ?
Valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é a maneira correta ou a mais fácil, mas voçê pode passar a variavel como parâmetro do link usado para navegar para a página 2 e definir na páginar 2 um método OnNavigatedTo para receber esse parâmetro, veja.

Na página 1:

```
private void btnNavegar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
Uri caminho = new Uri("/Pagina2.xaml?parametro=" + txtParametro.Text,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); 
NavigationService.Navigate(caminho); 
}
```

Na página 2:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
  string parametroRecebido; 
  if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("parametro", out parametroRecebido))
       { 
          MessageBox.Show("O paramêtro recebido foi : " + parametroRecebido); 
       } 
 }
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui , valeu :DDD, Mas se eu quiser passar mais de um parametro,  como faço ? valeu dnv:DD